# Synching without erasing songs on my iPhone

Tags: itunes

I managed to lose all my songs in my iTunes Library and cannot recover them, meaning that my iTunes Library is completely empty. I still have the songs on my iPhone however. I know I will have to upload songs into iTunes eventually. For the time being, I would simply like to add a few new songs to my empty iTunes and then upload them to my iPhone, but without doing anything that will cause me to erase the songs that are already on the iPhone. Is there a way to ADD songs without erasing the songs on my iPhone? I just cannot figure out how to sync without erasing existing playlists and songs on the iPhone.

Comment: The underlying cause of your frustration is the basic backbone of DRM free music.  In other words allowing users to do exactly what you want to do would basically allow free music sharing/swapping.

Answer (score 1):

I suspected that there was no way to get around it ... I guess I'll just have to start the laborious business of reconstructing my iTunes database by restoring all 3,000 songs ...

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Not any method I would recommend.

Could you put those new songs in Dropbox and listen from that app until you have time to sort out the larger issue of your iTunes data loss?